# postgres - calculating and grouping time difference

Tags: postgresql, timestamp, grouping

I have a DB table called `asset_history` that looks like this

```
 id         timestamp           Status       site_name       time_on_site
415 "2019-09-11 02:58:00.000"   "Entered"   "GF-R5-int" 
415 "2019-09-11 02:54:10.584"   "Left"      "GF-R5-int"     "189898"
415 "2019-09-11 02:51:00.687"   "Entered"   "GF-R5-int" 
415 "2019-09-11 02:37:34.136"   "Left"      "GF-R5-int"     "348257"
415 "2019-09-11 02:31:45.88"    "Entered"   "GF-R5-int"
```

I need to find out the total time spent by asset `415` on the site `GF-R5-int`. Assuming the current time is 2019-09-11 03:05:00.000, the total time spent by asset 415 on site GF-RT-int would be (348257+189898)ms + (2019-09-11 03:05:00.000 - 2019-09-11 02:58:00.000)ms... Which comes to a  total of 888155 ms. Below is the query I have got so far which only sums up the `time_on_site` values from the `Left` events. I'm unable to figure out how to add to it the time difference between current time and timestamp from the latest `Entered` event

```
select a.asset_id, at.name, count(*), sum(ah.time_spent_on_site)
from asset_history ah left outer join asset a on (ah.asset_id=a.id)
left outer join asset_type at on (a.asset_type=at.id)
where ah.asset_id=415
and ah.status='Left'
and ah.site_name='GF-R5-int'
group by a.asset_id, at.name
```

Comment: If `asset_history` already contains a column for the time spent on site, why can't you just sum that column?

Comment: Tim - As you can see in my query, I am already doing that. My problem is that I also need to add to that the time difference between current time and the most recent 'Entered' event. The 'Entered' events do not have a 'time_on_site' value present against them.

Comment: Please rephrase your question by showing clear sample input, lacking what you need, along with the output you want.

Comment: Tim - Rephrased

Comment: please post testable code.

Comment: Jasen - Not sure what you mean by "testable code". I already put up the full SQL query I'm trying to use

Comment: do you really have both an `id` and `asset_id` column in the`'asset` table?  your sample data is missing `asset_id` column...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

maybe like this.

```
select a.id, at.name, (count(*)+1)/2 as count, sum(ah.time_on_site) + case when count(*)&1 = 1 then  extract( epoch from now()) - extract( epoch from max(timestamp)) else 0 end * 1000    
from asset_history ah left outer join asset a on (ah.asset_id=a.id)
left outer join asset_type at on (a.asset_type=at.id)
where ah.asset_id=415
and ah.site_name='GF-R5-int'
group by a.id, at.name;
```

If you can be sure that there will always be the correct number of records.
a odd number of records means the most recent record is an enetered with no matching exit